# Rowfilter Select syntax using a value stored in a variable

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

I am using VB.NET and I need to use Datatable.Select to get a row which has a matching value.

Consider I have Datatable_A, which has many rows. I am interested to get row/rows which matches my search criteria. In this case, I must get a row (RowA), which has AnswerA stored in Column_A.

I know I can easily use the method below to find the answer:

```
RowA = Datatable_A.Select("Column_A  = 'AnswerA'")
```

However, value 'AnswerA' is stored in Variable_A.

I have tried using

```
RowA = Datatable_A.Select("Column_A  = 'Variable_A'")
```

Unfortunately, I still could not get the datarow, whose Column_A = 'Answer A'.

I have studied the explanation in this website [DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/), but I could not find any clue there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select a subset of your datatable rows using the `Select` method and a variable that contains the value to filter your rows you need to write

```
Dim Variable_A = "MySearchCriteria"
Dim rowsSelected = Datatable_A.Select("Column_A  = '" & Variable_A & "'")
```

This means that you want all the rows in which the `Column_A` (a string column) contains exactly the value "MySearchCriteria" stored in the `Variable_A`. The filter condition is created concatenating the literal string describing the name of the column and the operator with the content of the `Variable_A`. Since `Column_A` is assumed to be a string column then you need to encapsulate the `Variable_A` between single quotes.

And remember that Select returns an array of DataRow that match the filter expression.

```
For Each row in rowsSelected
    Console.WriteLine(row("Column_A").ToString)
Next
```